# django filters with pagination: showing same page after pressing next url

Tags: python, html, django, django-filter, django-pagination

When i search for something(like tom), it works well for first page. But if I click next page url, it shows the same result, nothing changes, but in url, it becomes **http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?caption=tom** to **http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?caption=tom&?page=2**

filters.py:

```
class VideoFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['caption']
        filter_overrides = {
             models.CharField: {
                 'filter_class': django_filters.CharFilter,
                 'extra': lambda f: {
                     'lookup_expr': 'icontains',
                 },
             },
         }
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    filterset = VideoFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    if filterset.is_valid():
        queryset = filterset.qs

    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    print(page_number)# always prints **none**
    queryset = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    
    return render(request, 'search.html',{
        'result': queryset,
        'caption': request.GET['caption'],
    })
```

search.html:

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}
{% block body %}

<!-- more code -->
{% if result.has_next %}
    <a href="?caption={{caption}}&?page={{result.next_page_number}}"><button>See more results</button></a>
{% endif %}

{% endblock body %}
```

navbar.html:

```
<!-- more code -->
<form action="/search/" method="GET"> <!-- working without csrf_token -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="caption" required />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
```

where is the problem?
how do i visit next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made an error in the URL of the button, the key-value pairs in the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) are separated by an *ampersand* (`&`), not an ampersand with question mark (<s>`&?`</s>). By writing it that way, Django will interpret this as:

```
>>> QueryDict('caption=tom&?page=2')
<QueryDict: {'caption': ['tom'], '?page': ['2']}>
```

so then the parameter is not <s>`page`</s>, but `?page`.

We can fix this by removing the question mark between the caption and the page in the URL:

```
<a href="?caption={{ caption|urlencode }}&page={{ result.next_page_number }}">
```

You should also use the [**`|urlencode`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) to prevent a wrong querystring, for example when the caption would have a questionmark, number sign (`#`), etc. The `|urlencode` filter will transform the text in [*percent encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).